# How to convert darknet image classification weights file to pytorch pt?

Tags: python, type-conversion, pytorch, darknet, image-classification

I created a model of darknet53.weights for image classification using my original data in darknet.
(This isn't a YOLO v3 model.)
Is there a way to convert a darknet53.weight to a pytorch pt model?

I tried quoting various codes on github etc., but all of them can convert only YOLOv3 weights file to pytorch's pt model.

I want to compare the accuracy of the darknet53 model created with darknet with other image classification models created with pytorch.
Initially, I tried to make a darknet53 model with pytorch, but that didn't work. Therefore, I created a darknet53 model with darknet.

If anyone knows a good way, please teach me.

Thanks.

Comment: you can try onnx for weight conversion